# How do get all tasks in

Tags: c#, foreach, enumerable, enumerator

How i can get an iterator for use in `Task.WaitAll` to wait for all task exist in `customList` with lowest overhead or lines of code ?

```
   public class Custom
    {
      public Task task;
      public  int result;
    }

public class Main
    {
       void doSomething()
       {
           List<Custom> customList=new List<>();
           //customList.Add(custom1,2,3,4,5.....);
           Task.WaitAll(????)
       }
    }
```

Comment: `Task.WaitAll(customList.Select(c => c.task).ToArray());`?

Comment: Why are you storing a Task in a class? A Task isn't a thread, it representes an execution. If you want to the results from a list of tasks, just use `var results=await Task.WhenAll(myListOfTasks);`. It's not identifiable either, so there is no reason to use a custom class to "wrap" it

Comment: @juharr the task.waitall is blocking call where task.whenAll is not  this mainly  the difference

Comment: In other words, as people have already answered in your previous questions, stop trying to use tasks as if they were threads or as if they need some kind of abstraction on top. They don't. You can get results from a list of urls with a single client with `var tasks=myUrls.Select(url=>client.GetStringAsync(url));var contents=await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`. You can combine URLs with results or checks with `var tasks=myUrls.Select(url=>{var response=client.GetStringAsync(url);return new {Url=url;Response=response};)`

Comment: @ColinM OP has confused tasks with Parallel.ForEach and async in a previous question today. The OP is asking aboug retrieving contents from multiple URLs in parallel

Comment: @ColinM yes I know but it was comment ans it was deleted

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel I know, I read the comment wrong or he fixed it by the time I posted my comment, which is why I deleted it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My reason for wraping them inside classes is to check which url returned which response in further proccessing. `customList` is actually filled by a for loop which use `GetAsync`. Reason is here I want to send Get Request in parallel and don't wait until completion just for one of them

Comment: @XX which you don't need to do at all. I already posted how a simple `Select` can return both results. You don't need the task, just the ulr and the result. You don't need `Parallel` either - that's for *data* parallelism and won't use more partitions/tasks than cores.

Answer (score 2):

Tasks aren't threads. They represent the *execution* of a function, so there is no point in storing them and their results as classes. Getting the results of multiple tasks is very easy if you use `Task.WhenAll`.

There is no reason to wrap the task in a class. You can think of *Task* itself as the wrapper over a thread invocation and is result.

If you want to retrieve the contents from multiple pages, you can use LINQ a single HttpClient to request the content from many pages at once. `await Task.WhenAll` will return the results from all tasks :

```
string[] myUrls=...;
HttpClient client=new HttpClient();
var tasks=myUrls.Select(url=>client.GetStringAsync(url));
string[] pages=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

If you want to return more data, eg check the contents, you can do so inside the `Select` lambda:

```
var tasks=myUrls.Select(async url=>
          {
              var response=await client.GetStringAsync(url);
              return new {        
                          Url=url,
                          IsSensitive=response.Contains("sensitive"),
                          Response=response
                         };
          });
var results =await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Results contains the anonymous objects generated inside `Select`. You can iterate or query them just like any other array, eg:

```
foreach(var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Url);
}
```